# Matching all subdomains except some from list in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to mach all subdomain for `example.com` (ex. `123.example.com`, `abc.example.com` etc.) except subdomains in this list:

- `main1`
- `main2`
- `main3`

This rule in `.htaccess` would help to change `robots.txt` to `robots_sub.txt` if a subdomain matched. Here is an example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?<!main1|main2|main3).+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots_sub.txt [L]
```

As a result it should be:

```
123.example.com - match
abc.example.com - match
main1.example.com - exclusion
zyx.example.com - match
main2.example.com - exclusion
main3.example.com - exclusion
sub.example.com - match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?<!main1|main2|main3).+\.example\.com$ [NC]
> ```

Use a **negative *lookahead***, rather than a **negative *lookbehind*** ***** here. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!(main1|main2|main3)\.)[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
:
```

Only subdomains that are exactly equal to `main1` or `main2` or `main3` are excluded. Subdomains that have a partial match (eg. `abcmain1` or `main1xyz`) are permitted.

Or, use a separate *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(main1|main2|main3)\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.example\.com$ [NC]
:
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* in the first *condition* negates the expression so it is successful when it does not match (ie. when the `Host` header does not start `main1.`, `main2.` or `main3.`). The second *condition* then confirms that it is a subdomain being requested and not the domain apex.

---

*Additional explanation:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?<!main1|main2|main3).+\.example\.com$ [NC]
> ```

***** In attempting to use a *negative lookbehind* in this way, you are trying to assert that the string `main1` (or `main2` or `main3`) does not exist *before* the start of the string (ie. *before* the `Host` header), which is not possible in this context, so is always going to be successful. In order to use a negative lookbehind you need to first match something that the stated string can come before. For example:

```
^.+(?<!^(main1|main2|main3))\.mywebsite\.com$
```

But this is less efficient than the *negative lookahead* used above.